# Triangle Inequality about complex numbers, special case

Tags: complex-numbers

At Spivak's calculus he treats the triangle inequality about complex numbers dividing into cases. Let $z$ and $w$ complex numbers, the inequality is clear if $z$ or $w$ are $0$.

$\lvert z+w \rvert$$\leq \lvert z \rvert + \lvert w \rvert$

Suppose that $z=\lambda w$, then it is straightforward to prove the inequality but divide in cases :
$\lambda<0$  and $\lambda>0$.

I can't see how is this straightforward and why do we need to divide into cases for $\lambda$.
After I do the algebraic manipulations it seems that it doesn't matter how $\lambda$ is.

My guess is that my approach is wrong, so if someone can give me a hint on how to initiate the proof would be a great help. Thank you

Comment: Please state  completely what the inequality is that you are talking about. And what exactly the cases are discusing. As it is, no one can understand .

Comment: what about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general approach : For real $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$: We have $$ \bullet \quad (a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_2^2+b_2^2)=(a_1b_2-a_2 b_1)^2+(a_1 a_2+b_1 b_2)^2\geq (a_1 a_2+b_1 b_2)^2.$$

For $z=a_1+i b_1$ and $w=a_2+i b_2$ we have $$|z+w|\leq |z|+|w|\iff |z+w|^2\leq (|z|+|w|)^2\iff $$  $$\iff  (a_1+a_2)^2+(b_1+b_2)^2\leq a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2 +2\sqrt {(a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_2^2+b_2^2)} \iff$$  $$ \iff 2 (a_1a_2+b_1b_2)\leq 2\sqrt {(a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_2^2+b^2)}.$$From $\bullet$ we have $$\sqrt {(a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_2^2+b_2^2)}\geq \sqrt {(a_1 a_2+b_1 b_2)^2}=|a_1a_2+b_1b_2|\geq a_1a_2+b_1b_2.$$

Remarks: The significance of the values $a_1b_2-a_2b_1$ and $a_1a_2+b_1b_2$ can be seen if we put $z$ and $w$ in polar form :$z=r_1(\cos t_1+i\sin t_1),\;w=r_2(\cos t_2+i\sin t_2)$ with real $t_1,t_2$ and non-negative real $r_1,r_2$. Then $a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1= r_1 r_2 \sin (t_2-t_1)$ and $a_1 a_2+b_1 b_2=r_1 r_2\cos (t_2-t_1).$ So  if $z\ne 0\ne w$  then $|z+w|=|z|+|w| \iff (\sin (t_2-t_1)=0\land \cos (t_2-t_1)=1) \iff z/w\in R^+.$

Comment: If we put $z,w$ in polar form to begin, we get $|z+w|^2\leq (|z|+|w|)^2\iff  r_1 r_2 (\cos t_1 \cos t_2+\sin t_1 \sin t_2) \leq r_1 r_2$ .  Observe that the LHS is $r_1 r_2 \cos (t_2-t_1).$

Comment: The equation $\bullet$ in my answer expresses $|z|^2 |w|^2=|z w|^2$.

Comment: can you explain about the case when $z=\lambda w$  @user254665

Comment: When $z=lw$ and $ l$ is real, we have $a_1b_2-a_2b_1=0.$ We can directly calculate  that $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ when $ l\geq 0$ and $|z+w|= |\;|z|-|w|\;|$  when $ l<0.$ Represent $ a+bi$ (with real $a.b$) as the point $(a,b)$ in the real plane $ R\times R .$ Then $|a+bi|$ is the distance from $(a,b)$ to $(0,0).$ When $z/w$ is real then $z,w,$ and the origin are co-linear.  In polar form $z=r (\cos t+i\sin t)$, where $ r=|z|,$ and for $z\ne 0,$  the angle $t$ is  between the $x$-axis  (which represents the reals) and the segment joining $z$ to the origin $(0,0)$ (measured  from the $x$-axis ).

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=(a_1,b_1), w=(a_2,b_2)$, suppose $z=lw$, then $z=(la_1,la_2)$

I want to prove $\lvert z+w \rvert \leq\lvert z\rvert+\lvert w\rvert$

calculate $\lvert z+w \rvert$ = $\bullet$:

$\bullet$=$\lvert (la_2,lb_2)+(a_2,b_2) \rvert$=$\lvert (la_2+a_2,lb_2+b_2)\rvert$= $\sqrt{(1+l)^2a^2+(1+l)^2b^2)}$=$\lvert 1+l \rvert$ $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

calculate $\lvert z \rvert+\lvert w \rvert$= $\star$ :

$\star$ =$\lvert (la_2,lb_2)\rvert$ + $\lvert (a_2,b_2) \rvert$= $\sqrt{l^2a^2+l^2b^2}$+$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$=$\rvert l \lvert$ + 1 $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

if l>$0$ then $\lvert 1+l \rvert$=$\rvert l \lvert$ + 1 then $\lvert z+w \rvert =\lvert z\rvert+\lvert w\rvert$

if l