# Spivak, Ch. 25, "Complex Numbers": Prove $|z+w|\leq |z|+|w|$, $z$ and $w$ complex numbers when $z=\lambda w$. Must we consider separate cases?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

Consider the task of proving that $|z+w|\leq |z|+|w|$, where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers.

We can consider three cases:

1. $|z|$ or $|w|$ equal to $0$
2. $z=\lambda w$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
3. $z\neq \lambda w$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

My question is about case (2) specifically.

There is are similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671369/triangle-inequality-about-complex-numbers-special-case) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968175/if-z-and-w-are-two-complex-numbers-prove-that-zw-zw) but those solutions are different from the one below, which I am asking about.

**My proof of case (2) is**

$$|z+w| = |\lambda w + w|=|(1+\lambda)w|$$

$$=|((1+\lambda)w_1, (1+\lambda)w_2)|$$

$$=\sqrt{(1+\lambda)^2 (w_1^2+w_2^2)}$$

$$|1+\lambda||w|$$

$$\leq (1+|\lambda|)|w|$$

$$=|w|+|z|$$

where I used $|z|=\sqrt{\lambda^2(w_1^2+w_2^2)}=|\lambda||w|$.

But then I noticed that in Spivak's *Calculus* he says to consider separately the cases $\lambda>0$ and $\lambda<0$, and I am not doing this.

**My questions then are:**

- is the proof above incorrect?
- why do we need to consider the cases separately?

Comment: I notice that you use triangle inequality on $\Bbb{R}$ to get $|1 + \lambda||w| \le (1 + |\lambda|)|w|$. You would have to prove the triangle inequality on $\Bbb{R}$ first in order to get this result. I can see why Spivak avoids doing this: a separate proof in the $\Bbb{R}$ case is a little inelegant, and it could almost come across as circular to the untrained eye (e.g. a large proportion of people reading a calculus textbook).

Comment: Your proof is correct but I think what Spivak had in mind is what DanielWainfleet says in the last comment of your 1st link. Btw in your post you should specify $\lambda\in\Bbb R.$

Comment: I think for real $a$ and $b$, the inequality $|a + b|\le |a| + |b|$, with *strict* inequality iff $a$ and $b$ have different signs, is fairly basic. It is taught in school well before the complex numbers are taught.

Comment: @TheoBendit Perhaps you are right. However, this is one of the final chapters in the book. The triangle inequality for real numbers has been proved various times in the book already.

Comment: Surely just expanding $|z+w|^2$ and upper bounding the real part that appears would be more straightforward?

Answer (score 1):

You did however, consider each of the two subcases of Case 2 $z=\lambda w$, with one subcase $\lambda <0$ and the other subcase $\lambda >0$. Indeed, in your inequality $|1+\lambda||w| \le (1+|\lambda|)|w|$, the "$\le$" is true for all real values of $\lambda$. You have on the one hand **equality** [which the "$\le$" allows] if $\lambda$ is positive [or if $\lambda$ is $0$ for that matter], and you have on the other hand **strict** inequality if $\lambda$ is negative.

I

Comment: @geetha290krm $\lambda$ is indeed real, as there is a Case 3: $z \not = \lambda w$. Otherwise if $w$  is nonzero there is always such a $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct but I think what Spivak had in mind is what DanielWainfleet says in the last comment of your 1st link:

*"We can directly calculate that $|z+w|=|z|+|w|$ when $\lambda≥0$ and $|z+w|=||z|−|w||$ when $\lambda<0.$"*